# .htaccess dont let php file load on jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, .htaccess

hello guys i have a `jquery.post` and i included a php file:

```
$.post('website/register/checks.php'
```

when i execute the function data goes to the file, but i have a rule in my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule p/(.*)/ index.php?p=$1
```

and because of this istead of getting the information from the php file, i get my home page in the place where the data is supposed to go to. any way i can fix this to let the jquery pass the data properly?
do i need to make a rule or change something in the htaccess file?

Comment: I don't understand. Your rewrite rule does not match that request so why would it even come into play?

Comment: re rewrite rule is how i set up my urls, but in the jquery i specify where my file(checks.php) is, and it completely messes up with my rule of the URLS how would i be able to allow this file to execute properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following rule to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

This will cause the `RewriteRule` to only process URLs that don't match an existing file. So `website/register/checks.php` would request that actual file, while `website/register/checks` would request `index.php?p=website/register/checks`.

Comment: How does `p/(.*)/` match `website/register/checks`?

Comment: It's possible that he was running the JS on a `p/(.*)/` URL, and since the `$.post()` call wasn't an absolute URI, it would be relative. Considering he accepted my answer, that was probably the issue.

Comment: Ah, great pickup on the relative URL. +1